# Qt build for Wince works, but no plugins or import work

Tags: qt, windows-ce

I've got Qt build for a CE 6 custom sdk.  I can use VS2005 and a KITL connection and run several of the Qt examples successfully on the device.  I can also run examples if I copy all of the Qt dll's into a directory with the .exe on a USB drive and attach it to the device.

However, it seems that anything that uses QTDIR to find the location doesn't work (plugins and QML imports).  I was able to get some QML examples to work if I included the qml in the project as a resource file.

Nothing I've tried works (including copying the plugins/imports to a directory with the dlls).  I can't set QTDIR, as wince doesn't have environment settings.

I was able to get a little further with a static build vs. shared, but I believe that "nice stuff" like QtWebkit and QtMobility won't be available for static builds.

Is there some secret to deployment on wince that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked it down.  In src/corelib/io/qfilesystemiterator_win.cpp there is a code chunk:

```
if (QSysInfo::windowsVersion() >= QSysInfo::WV_WINDOWS7) {
    dwAdditionalFlags = 2;  // FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH
    infoLevel = 1 ;         // FindExInfoBasic;
}
```

The enums for windowsVersion for wince (6.0) are different, causing this to trigger as true instead of false.  Wrapping the above code in

```
#ifndef Q_OS_WINCE
...
#endif
```

fixes the problem.

Note, I found a git repo for Windows Embedded Compact 7 patches that (as of 4.8.0) is not included in Qt.  This fix is one of the changes.  Check out https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/jaanttils-qt/graph/WEC7_Patches if you are working on 4.8 and wince (even CE 6).  I needed a handful of changes on top, but I think they were specific to the sdk I'm using.